# Save canvas to device memory, using phonegap 2.1.0

Tags: html, cordova, canvas, base64

I've a canvas where I perform some visual operations. I would like to save the image into the Documents folder of my application, but i'm encountering some trouble with the data path encoded in base64. Is there a way to encode that data to be saved as a binary?

Comment: Related post [Canvas to .jpg file with Cordova Phonegap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37686630)