# Canvas to .jpg file with Cordova Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, canvas

I'm trying to store a canvas in my divice, reading in internet i found that i have to convert my canvas to [Base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL), nice, i did it...

Then i searched a function to store a base64 with cordova and just found a [function](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#store-an-existing-binary-file-) that stores a Blob object, so i searched again and found a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419574/saving-dataurlbase64-to-file-on-phonegap-android/29138662#29138662) that converts my base64 to Blob, and nice again, it apparently works, but when i go to the file explorer i'm just getting a file that says in plain text (and changing its extension to .txt ):

> [object Uint8Array][object Uint8Array]

This is my final code:

```
   function draw() {
        window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5 * 1024 * 1024, function (fs) {
        console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
        getSampleFile(fs.root);
        }, errorHandler);
   }


  function getSampleFile(dirEntry) {

  var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
   if (canvas.getContext) {
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     //...some code to customize the canvas

     //var mURI = canvas.toDataURL();
     var mURI = canvas.toDataURL().replace(/data:image\/png;base64,/,'');

     var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
     saveFile(dirEntry, b64toBlob(mURI,"image/png","512") , x+".png");
            }

  }

  function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
    contentType = contentType || '';
    sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;
    console.log('Estoy en B64');

    var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
    var byteArrays = [];

    for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
        var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

        var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

        byteArrays.push(byteArray);
    }
    console.log('ByteArrays'+byteArrays);
    var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});

    return blob;
  }


function saveFile(dirEntry, fileData, fileName) {
    console.log('1. DIRENTRY:'+dirEntry+', 2 FILEDATA:'+fileData+',3 FILENAME:'+fileName);
      dirEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

          writeFile(fileEntry, fileData);

      }, errorHandler);
  }

  function writeFile(fileEntry, dataObj, isAppend) {

fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {

    fileWriter.onwriteend = function() {
        console.log("Successful file write...");
    };

    fileWriter.onerror = function(e) {
        console.log("Failed file write: " + e.toString());
    };

    fileWriter.write(dataObj);
});
}
```

I hope you can help me, the main goal of this is to store a picture with a watermark, so if you have another idea please tell me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to add a `water mark` you may refer following links

[W3School Link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage) 
[Jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sangdol/RsxtG/49/)

**EDITED**

```
var yourCanvas = document.getElementById('yourCanvasId');
var context = yourCanvas.getContext('2d');
var waterMarkImg = document.getElementById("waterMarkImageId");
context.drawImage(waterMarkImg, 0, 0, yourCanvas.width, yourCanvas.height);
var basse64 = yourCanvas.toDataURL();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Charitha Goonewardena , but i'm already doing that... the problem is storing that canvas element as a png or jpeg file

Comment: You can simply convert your canvas to a base64 String. I have edited my answer. Hope its helpful. anything need buzz me =) good luck

Comment: Thanks again @Charitha Goonewardena, that is in the code above, what i need is a function  to store that base64 string as a .jpg or .png, I was searching in cordova documentation but could not find something that fits it, i'll be very grateful if you can help me

Comment: Are you going to do it in javascript ? I have implemented the backend part using C#. I can help with that